# Is there a method to do an ALTER Column in postgres 12 on an huge table without waiting a lifetime?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-12

Is there a method to do an ALTER COLUMN in postgres 12 on an huge table without waiting a lifetime?

I try to convert a field from bigint to smallint :

```
ALTER TABLE huge ALTER COLUMN result_code TYPE SMALLINT;
```

It takes 28 hours, is there a  smarter method?
The table has sequences, keys and foreign keys

Comment: What is the original type? If you hope to reduce storage space by changing `integer` to `smallint` it's probably not going to make a difference.

Comment: The smarter alternatives would depend on why you are doing it in the first place.

Comment: the original type is bigint, and I found many fields of type bigint that can be easily smallint, and there is a 10 -15 % space gain which is necessary to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table has to be rewritten, and you have to wait.

If you have several columns whose data type you want to change, you can use several `ALTER COLUMN` clauses in a single `ALTER TABLE` statement and save time that way.

An alternative idea would be to use logical replication: set up an empty copy of the database (`pg_dump -s`), where your large table is defined with `smallint` columns. Replicate your database to that database, and switch over as soon as replication has caught up.

Comment: tried this way, but the total time doesn't change too much

Comment: It will still rewrite the table, but only once. It won't get better than that.

Comment: super, I 'll try it !

Comment: It's working! the replica hasen't finished yet, but it seems faster than the former procedure